# Sinusbot script : How to detect when a client moves in a channel?

Tags: javascript

I am currently developing a script which aims to create channels automatically. So to start I need to know when a client moves. I tried little things that didn't work. Indeed when a client joins the bot channel and then leaves it the test message displays well but if I move to any other channel I have no message displayed. Here is my code :

```
registerPlugin({
    name: 'Auto-channel-creator',
    version: '1.0',
    description: 'generate auto channel',
    author: 'Erem <>',
    vars: []
}, function(_, config, meta) {

    let event = require('event');
    let engine = require('engine');
    let backend = require('backend');

    event.on('clientMove', ({ client , toChannel }) => {
            client.poke("gg");
    })
});
```

Sinusbot [documentation](https://sinusbot.github.io/scripting-docs/)

Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0):

You've to enable "subscription" mode and subscribe to all channels you want to get notifies from else you'll not getting any server wide move actions.
https://sinusbot.github.io/scripting-docs/#enginesetsubscriptionmode

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I activated the "subscription" mode and I am already subscribed to all the channels but it still does not work. Do I have to store something in the store?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you're really subscribed to every channel, but to ensure this you could iterate over all channels and explicitly subscribe them (https://sinusbot.github.io/scripting-docs/#channelsubscribe).